# How to change the docker volume default storage path for the Linux based containers in Windows host using volumes

Tags: docker

I am using Linux based container on Windows 10 host. Currently when we create a volume for this container, then the data is stored under the below path which is the default path:

```
\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\myvol2\_data
```

So, whatever changes I do in this host directory are reflected correctly in docker container and vice-a-versa.
Is there any solution by which I can change it to a custom location i.e. my project directory for e.g. `D:\Java\MyProject` on the host ?

I know we can use bind-mount, but I want to use volumes.

Answer (score 0):

in your docker run command add the volume specification:

```
-v C:\Users\your.name\projects:/home/yourlinux/dir
```

Comment: But I want to know using volumes, not bind-mount.